# Getting a date value in a postgres table column and check if it's bigger than todays date

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a Postgres table called clients. The name column contains certain values eg.

test23233 [987665432,2014-02-18]

At the end of the value is a date, I need to compare this date, and return all records where this specific date is younger than today

I tried

```
select id,name FROM clients where name ~ '(\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2})';
```

but this isn't returning any values. How would I go about to achieve the results I want?

Comment: Do you need to do this once or several times? (In order words, is the value of "today" constant or not?) Also, try `select id,name FROM clients where name ~ $$(?p)\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$$;` and see if that is going to return any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing something similar to

```
select id,substring(name,'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}'),name FROM clients where substring(name,'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}') > '2011-03-18';
```

Might not be the best practice, but it works. But open to better suggestions

Comment: Note that this won't work well if your months/days can *actually* be stored in a single digit, e.g. 2011-3-5. You'll need to enforce double digits, i.e. 2011-03-05 for the same date. You can then change your regex to use `{2}` instead of `{1,2}`.

Comment: @Jon - Yes your right, did not think in that direction, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1):

If the data is always stored this way (i.e. after the comma), I would not use a regex, but extract the date part and convert it to a proper date type.

```
SELECT *
FROM the_table
WHERE to_date(substring(name, strpos(name, ',') + 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') < current_date
```

You might want to put that to_date(...) thing into a view to make this easier for other queries.

In the long run you should realy (really) try to fix that data model.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression for this would be extremely hard. Is it possible to change the schema and data to separate the name, whatever the second value is, and the timestamp into separate columns? That would be far more logical, less error prone, and significantly faster.

Otherwise, I suspect you'll have to use some sort of parsing (possibly a regex) to extract the date, then convert it to a Postgres date, then compare *that* with the current time... for every single row. Ick.

EDIT: Actually, it's not *quite* that bad... because your dates are stored in a sort-friendly way, it's possible that you could do the extraction (whether with a regex or anything else) and just do an ordinal comparison with the string representation of today's date, without actually performing any date conversion for each row. It's still ugly though, and doesn't validate that the date isn't (say) 2011-99-99. If you can *possibly* store the data more sensibly, do.

Comment: unfortunately not possible to change the schema. It will be easier not doing it the regular expression way but unfortunately I cant modify the schema

Comment: @Roland: do try to change the schema. Storing data like that is begging for problems (data and performance!)